# What is an "Honest" Accumulation Point?

Tags: general-topology, definition

The term comes up in a paper here https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.3560.pdf bottom of page 4.

I haven't found any explanation for this with Google or the textbooks available to me.

Comment: I imagine that the meaning is somewhat colloquial, and it means that those are accumulation points which are somehow "really accumulation points", rather than points inside the set, which happen to be accumulation points because of somewhat trivial reasons.

Comment: The statement in the article is actually the definition of "honest". That's why it is in brackets. The term might be used later again by these authors but it doesn't mean that this is a commonly used term.

Comment: @H.Gutsche. Thanks, that seems a reasonable suggestion except that the term doesn't come up again in the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just an ad hoc, colloquial term they introduce (but not reuse) to distinguish it from the first type they just discussed, and which they consider "boring" or "trivial" in some sense. That's how I read it. Don't look for any deep technical meaning...